# DirectXTK Model : How to draw with custom vertex & pixel shader?

Tags: directx11, 3d-meshes, fbx

Here is the code I use to render a `.cmo` (from `.fbx`) mesh :

```
void Render()
{
    assert(g_d3dDevice);
    assert(g_d3dDeviceContext);

    Clear(Colors::LimeGreen, 1.0f, 0);

    //g_d3dDeviceContext->VSSetShader(g_d3d_GEOM_VertexShader, nullptr, 0);
    //g_d3dDeviceContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 3, g_d3dConstantBuffers);

    g_d3dDeviceContext->RSSetState(g_d3dRasterizerState);
    g_d3dDeviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &g_Viewport);

    //g_d3dDeviceContext->PSSetShader(g_d3d_GEOM_PixelShader, nullptr, 0);
    //g_d3dDeviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &g_SkyboxShaderRessourceView);

    g_d3dDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_d3dRenderTargetView, g_d3dDepthStencilView);
    g_d3dDeviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(g_d3dDepthStencilState, 1);

    // Draw ship
    std::unique_ptr<CommonStates> states(new CommonStates(g_d3dDevice));
    DGSLEffectFactory fx(g_d3dDevice);
    auto testMesh = Model::CreateFromCMO(g_d3dDevice, L"media/meshes/space-frigate/space_frigate_6.cmo", fx, false);
    testMesh->Draw(g_d3dDeviceContext, *states, g_WorldMatrix, g_ViewMatrix, g_ProjectionMatrix);

    Present(g_EnableVSync);
}
```

[image: Test render]

[image]

What puzzles me :

1. How do I use my own vertex / pixel shaders instead of the auto-generated ones ? Notice I commented the line where I set the shaders and it works just as well...
2. What is the `CommonStates` object and what is it used for ? It doesn't seem to do anything even when adding i.e. `states->Wireframe();`
3. Why is an `DGSLEffectFactory` required and what is it used for ?
4. Why does the Z-test fail in the 2nd image ?

All in all : should I write my own mesh loader instead to rely on custom vertex / pixel shaders ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be loading the model every frame. Just load it once and render it over and over as needed. Also, you should create the `DGSLEffectFactory` and `CommonStates` once and reuse it.

1. The design is for you to implement your own `IEffectFactory` and then you can return your own custom `IEffect` for custom shaders. You can also control the individual subset drawing instead of calling `Model::Draw`. See [ModelMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ModelMesh) for details.
2. The `CommonStates` object is a factory for 'stock' states. The `Model` drawing uses it to set the default states. You can use it directly. For example, to set a wireframe rendering mode: `g_d3dDeviceContext->RSSetState(states->Wireframe());` It's a helper object so you don't end up creating lots of redundant states for common combinations.
3. The `IEffectFactory` interface you pass to the `Model` loader is the abstraction for creating `IEffect` instances (i.e. shaders) and for loading textures. The default ones also handle 'material and texture sharing' so you don't create unique instances for every single model's material.
4. I can't tell exactly what's wrong based on our snippet, but a common thing to have go wrong is right-handed vs. left-handed view coordinates vs. the winding of the model. You can try passing a 'true' at the end of the loader to see if that worked.

The general model of [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) is to provide you a solid starting point. You can then replace portions as you want. That said, it's best to really understand how it works before moving on your own solution. I suggest you take the time to work through the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) for a comprehensive introduction to using Direct3D 11 and the library.

Comment: I'm still very confused at what an *effect* is. Is it a file ? What does it contain ? How do I integrate an effect into my project ? How do I link it inside my code ? What is it's purpose ? I don't see the pros too at using `Model::CreateFromXXX` / `Draw()` when forcing custom shaders (as you said is possible) because the main workload I see is shader code (stuff I need to learn like texture mapping / specular / what else) versus loading an `.obj` file I can do using a library like https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader I found today. What is your opinion on this ?

Comment: In _DirectX Tool Kit_, a [IEffect](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/IEffect) is just an abstract interface for setting up shaders. The library includes a selection of 'built-in effects' and the shader binaries are included directly into static library to avoid the need to deal with runtime loading of shader binary files. Again, you should read through the docs on the DirectX Tool Kit [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki) and work through the tutorial to make sure you have the foundation to move to custom shaders.

Comment: You can of course write your own model loader and renderer with or without _DirectX Tool Kit_. It's just a convenience library that supports ``.cmo``, ``.sdkmesh``, and ``.vbo`` binary formats that can map those format's materials to either the built-in XNA Game Studio like BasicEffects or to the Visual Studio Starter Kit DGSL effects system. The problem you are having is more basic than 'writing your own shader', and that's why I recommend you work through the foundational material first to make sure you haven't missed something unrelated in your understanding.

Comment: I am already fairly advanced at writing my own shaders and compiling / mixing / using them (example http://grid.turtlespeak.net/upload/LMo6pu2bZ3pYC5QU/lMiQKOZTmLoMe9nF/mandelbox-1.png pure HLSL pixel shader raytracing). My main concern was : I need data computed in custom shaders for classic geometry as well (I.E. per-pixel distance from the PoV for polygon meshes) that I obviously can't have at using auto-generated shaders. The drawback from this is I have then to implement the stuff in said shaders like Phong etc... Loading meshes isn't really the issue : I need flexibility with shaders.

Comment: You can always provide your own shaders and even take over the drawing directly from the ``ModelMesh`` and ``ModelMeshPart`` code if desired. Or you can wrap your custom shaders in the ``IEffect`` interface and create them in your own ``IEffectFactory``. My main concern is that you first figure exactly why the 'stock' shaders aren't rendering as you expect.

Comment: Are you referring to the Z-test glitch ? Actually I still have this problem even when creating the mesh / etc... outside the `Render()` func and only calling `Draw()` inside it. I thought creating the mesh all over again caused the artifacts but that's not the case (the winding in the snippet is correct too). I decided to move to `.obj` loading  - I'll see if it fixes this issue.

Comment: You can of course go with a custom model loader and renderer, but another approach would be to use [DirectXTK template and tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Rendering-a-model) to setup a simple render test of that model. If that works, then you can track back what you did differently in your app.

Comment: Note that if you have the model in ``.obj`` form, you can also try using the [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh) **meshconvert** tool to create a ``.cmo`` directly from it and see how that works for you. If nothing else, you can make use of the ``WaveFrontReader`` class in the DirectXMesh utilities folder as a quick test.

Comment: I didn't notice you are the guy maintining DXTK :) Well... thanks for the tutorial link - will try setting it up and compare. I have the model both in `.obj` and `.fbx` formats - what I did is open the `.fbx` in VS2015, compile it and load the compiled `.cmo`. Now I'm pretty sure the problem is with the depth/stencil object (which makes perfect sense). I could modifiy my DS object with no resulting change in the render i.e. change the comparison func from `LESS` to `GREATER` - no difference. I wonder if TK creates a depth/stencil context on the fly too ? I planned on testing this too.

Comment: I've caught the lizard. Problem was my near plane was way too small (`0.000001f`) hence the glitches. Such a value may seem stupid but I'll need to handle very small distances indeed. Now setting it to `0.01f` fixed the issue - at least temporarily.